# Decorating text by adding new line after sequence of words

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I've used this css code : `width:90%; word-break:break-all;` it works and breaks the text ,but it breaks it whether the word is completed or not ( it may split the letters of the words ) so I want to improve this so that it will break after the word is completed ( doesn't split the word )
**Note that** : I'm using a label to show the text this is the code :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("subject") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I want to determine if the word has been written (shown) completely before breaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below.

```
word-break:keep-all;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Label{
    white-space: pre;         
    white-space: pre-wrap;   
    white-space: pre-line; 
    white-space: -pre-wrap;  
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

Comment: this will break each word under that label